# Reducedness of image of projection

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Consider the ruled surface $F_2$. Let $C_0$ be the special section where $C_0^2=-2$ and $f$ a general fiber. We can embed $F_2$ into $\mathbb{P}^6$ using the linear system |$C_0+4f$|, which makes $C_0$ a conic in $\mathbb{P}^6$. Suppose we take a general point $p$ on the plane spanned by $C_0$ in $\mathbb{P}^6$ and let $S$ be the image of $F_2$ by projecting from $p$. $S$ is a degree $5$ surface in $\mathbb{P}^5$. $S$ is singular at the image of $C_0$, which is a line.

My question is : is $S$ reduced?

It seems $S$ should be reduced by exercise 2.3.11(d) in Hartshorne, (which says the scheme-theoretic image of a reduced scheme is just the reduced induced structure on the closure of the (set-theoretic) image) But I am having trouble understanding what happens at the singular locus.

Thanks!

Comment: The exercise you cite is about closed subschemes; is this the one you meant to cite? If so, which part? In general, you should write your question so that it can be parsed without the reader having to consult a book.

Comment: @TabesBridges Thank you for your comment. I have edited the question per your suggestion.